# NFC Tag Type 1 Protection

Tags: android, nfc

I got a Type 1 NFC TAG from NXP semiconductor ... i tried many android applications to reset or format and never worked , it says Protected or Blocked .
The question is , how can i crack the NFC Card protection.

Comment: NXP does not manufacture Type 1 Tags, so you are probably mistaken about the tag type or the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type1 NFC Tags have a simple but effective protection mechanism.

There are one time programmable lock bits on the tag. Each of this lock bits makes 8 bytes of data on the tag read only (simplified view).

Once these bits are set the memory is write protected for ever. Think of the lock bits as fuses: Once they are blown there is no way to un-blow them. There is also no master key to put the tag into read/write state or so.

Long story short: There is nothing you could crack on a Type1 NFC tag.

Comment: i need a huge favour, would like to be able to contact you directly.
1. I don't quite understand the protection mechanism from what you wrote. If each bit corresponds to 8 bytes, then only 16 bytes can be made read only?
2. How do I permanently lock only partial part of the entire memory? (In Android)
3. You've mentioned that there are no master keys involved, but is there a master reset functionality to re-write EVERYTHING in the tag?

Comment: @AkashRamani, Yes, you can contact me directly. Regarding your questions: 1 and 2) Download the official spec and read on Lockbytes: http://tinyurl.com/o2vgf3n 3) There is no master reset functionality. Once you've locked the tag it is read-only.

Comment: I'm not able to contact you directly on StackOverflow :/ or maybe i just don't know how to. I did check out the manual but i'm still a little hazy about how to implement this. Specially in android. Basically, is there an email i can contact you by?

Comment: Just google my name. You'll find a working e-mail address in the first 10 hits. It's just as simple.

Comment: @AkashRamani Finding an e-mail address is no rocket science :-(

Comment: @AkashRamani I even linked my web-site in my profile. Click on it, and you'll find contact informations.

Comment: I did google you, went to the website and all, the only contactable location seemed to be twitter.

Comment: Click on "impressum". It's really as easy as that.

Comment: Honestly, I have a head-hunter filter. I don't give out my email on the phone but +ask them to to contact me via e-mail. They ought to find my e-mail address on google. You failed. I will very likely not not fix stuff for you if you fail this simple test.